# Servlet not updating on ant

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant

I am making an application for google-appengine. I am using google app engine sdk for java and using
ant 1.8 for starting development server and jdk 1.6, jre1.6.

The problem: Whenever i make changes to my java servlet they don't get reflected in the webpage. Infact, my browser displays the old servlet and its errors. I compiled and recompiled my servlet code,
restarted the server but it doesn't effect any change. Still it runs the old servlet code. I deleted my servlet class file but it still shows up. That's too much. How can it run something that doesn't exist.I tried clearing the browser cache and temp files but nothing changed.

can somebody suggest me what to do in this case ? how to make ant use the new servlet?

Please help!

PS: The problem solves when i restart my pc. Also logging off solves it but it is very annoying because testing even a single variable change ask for a restart or logoff.I searched my pc for any files that might be saved somewhere but i didn't get it.

Comment: Try deleting target directory before build.

Comment: I tried deleting the directory under web-inf/classes that holds my .class file. Still the same.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. Anybody?

Comment: It's really hard to help if we know nothing about your build environment. But, 1. make sure your java source is actually saved 2. run ant 3. make sure ant compiles changed classes (look at build directory, check time on files). 4. make sure server uses those changed classes (= they get copied to dev server run directory)

Comment: @PeterKnego : Thanks for the suggestion. While i was looking for answers i found that the answer was simple. My files were being compiled properly and placed in right folders. The problem was that i somehow the javaTm binary was still running after i killed the server.Due to multiple java processes on my pc i couldn't recognize the fact. Somebody told me to look for such dummy processes. When i killed the last javaTm binary it got corrected. Thus i have to kill the ant specific binary eveytime and don't need to reboot or even log-off.

Comment: Good to hear. Maybe you should make taht into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a dummy java binary running even when i stopped the server. I have to kill it manually to stop old class files to be executed.